# Endpoint not found exception in a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-endpoint

I'm approaching to WCF Service, starting with the tutorial provided by Microsoft. I created a very simple WCF Service (`CalculatorService`) and I've some doubts about the `EndpointAddress` of this service.

When I create the WCF Host, I set the Endpoint like this:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/");
// Step 2 Create a ServiceHost instance
ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddress);
// Step 3 Add a service endpoint.
selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");
```

Everything works if I debug the entire solution, but, if I launch the WCFHost executing its .exe file, launching also the application of the Client gives me the following exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: No endpoint listening in http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Address/WcfServiceLibrary/Service1/.
```

The fact is that if I try to open a browser and search the address `http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/`, I get correctly the page of the Service. I suppose that the Service is hosted at one address and the Client tries to access to it via a different one.

Could anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Something somewhere else is expecting it to be on port 8732 clearly...

Comment: You're declaring an endpoint on the URL localhost:8000, and the WCFHost is looking for an endpoint on localhost:8732. Port on both are different.

Comment: yes, but the address http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Address/WcfServiceLibrary/Service1/ is created automatically. I didn't set it, so how can I force the client to search the service at the address I want?

Comment: Double click on the properties of your WCF service. Go to "Web" and modify the Project Url.

Answer (score 0):

If you have, in the client code, hard coded this address http://localhost:8732, then change it there. But your client is probably (you didn't put that info unfortunately in your question) automatically generated. In that case client config is in App.config file(if we are talking about your solution), and in config file of the .exe file when you build your project. You should look into your [ClientApplicationName].exe.config file and update the endpoint address to port 8000.